# AS2 - Trying to create a grid of boxes

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

This is my current code:

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("noteGrid", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
for(i = 1; i <= 14; i++){
    currentBlock = _root.noteGrid.attachMovie("block", "block" + i, _root.noteGrid.getNextHighestDepth);
    currentBlock._x = Math.floor(i / 7) * 25;
    currentBlock._y = (i % 7) * 25;
}
```

I have a movieclip with linkage set to block. When I compile this, the block appears however they are all on top of each other. When I used trace commands to find `currentBlock._x`, they are the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your setting of depths.

```
_root.noteGrid.getNextHighestDepth
```

You are trying to access a property of `noteGrid`, if you trace it you will see it tells you it is a function, rather than calling a function. To call the function do

```
_root.noteGrid.getNextHighestDepth()
```

By the looks of things your code isn't quite what you want but that can't really be fixed without you giving more details about what you're trying to do. Assuming you're trying to make a 2x7 grid, then you'll want to change your for loop to

```
for(i = 0; i < 14; i++)
```